# Снятие фокуса с кнопки

Tags: c++, qt, gui, qt5

Как снять фокус с кнопки при нажатии на пустую область формы(область формы, где нет ни одного виджета)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В обработчике нажатия на форму напишите `setFocus();`, или, если это `QMainWindow` наследник, тогда `centralWidget()->setFocus();`. Таким образом фокус перейдёт с кнопки на виджет.
Например, это можно сделать так:

```
void MainWindow::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *)
{
    centralWidget()->setFocus();
}
```

Т.е. Вы переопределяете виртуальную функцию `mousePressEvent` в Вашем `QMainWindow`

Comment: в QMainWindow і QWidget нет сигнала clicked, переопределить метод event в QMainWindow или QWidget?

Comment: @Тарас, обновил ответ